# How to join values and text in Google Sheets while ignoring blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I have a table with companies in rows and products in columns.

I want to output a summary of the order in a single cell i.e. taking the values from the table and adding the product name and variant while ignoring empty cells. See image for reference, the red text is the wanted result.

[image: Example table with red text as the wanted result.]

Do I use CONCAT, JOIN, TEXTJOIN or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B3:J,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,textjoin(", ",1,index(if(len(Σ),Σ&"x "&B2:J2&" "&scan(,B1:J1,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),))))))
```

[image]

Comment: If I may add, it's not exactly the same as in my example in reality.
I have the main product name (Apples) but the subcategories don't have a header and I'd rather abbreviate them to make the list succinct.